# SharePoint Content Search Web Part

Tags: content-search-web-part

I have created one Product list which contains "title" and "brand" column. I have created the query for "title" and "brand" in the content search web part by using a query string.

If I pass some value in the query string then the items are displaying in the content search web part.

Like if I access URL: https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/product.aspx?brand=mobile
Then it is displaying the result in a content search web part.

When I am not passing any query string value then the results are not coming.

My requirement here is if no query string value then it should show all the items from the list and if some value is there then it should show items belongs to that particular item.

Means when I access https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/product.aspx URL it should show all the items from the list.

Currently, I am using "RefinableString03:{QueryString.brand}" query in the content search web part.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display all items if you are using for filtering RefinableString, you must create content QueryWP without any filters pointing to the list and create another webPart with Refiners for etc and this will be used for filtering. You can also edit link as you wrote.